# How do I properly execute or call a Msys2 Mingw64 application from within Powershell 7+ (Outside of bash)?

Tags: powershell, msys2, exiv2

I downloaded and installed MSYS2, as well as some packages via Pacman. I also installed [exiv2](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-exiv2) from here. I am developing a Pwsh module that will be manipulating metadata, and I want to call `exiv2` from within Pwsh.

I tried copying `exiv2.exe` and `libexiv2.dll` from `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to a directory that I have added to PATH, but it doesn't seem to work outside of the MINGW64 shell (exiv2 -h prints nothing). So I guess I have to invoke it some other way, unless I'm missing something important.

What is the procedure for invoking this outside of bash? Do I have to invoke it by first calling bash / mintty in Pwsh, or is there a way to directly get what I want?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I actually figured it out. I feel stupid, but I didn't realize exiv2 distributes native Windows binaries on the homepage. So the whole reason I wanted to use MSYS2 is negated. Just dropped the exe and dependencies into PATH and all works as expected.